Requires a polymorphic field to allow multiple selections in Dynamics CRM/365
I'm working on a project that requires a polymorphic field to allow multiple selections. I'm wondering if a PCF control can be used to achieve this. If so, please provide guidance and examples.

polymorphic lookups allow a single selection between multiple tables. you need to select a single record or multiple records from a table (n:n relationship?)

@GuidoPreite Thanks for a comment, currently I have taken an approach of N:N but till is there any chance to use polymorphic lookup.
